# Vuforia Unity Export to Android Doesn't Quit Application On Clicking Back Button

Tags: android, android-layout, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I've recently exported an Android Vuforia app using Unity's Vuforia extension. The app works perfectly, and I have not done any modifications to it.

So, now when try to quit the app after testing it, it does not leave. I just hear the back button's noise and the application stays on.

Eventually when I click the home button it goes to the home screen, but this doesn't seem very efficient.

I'm very very new to Android, so is there a way to solve this? Either with Vuforia's extension or is there a button I can make to exit the app, and if yes, please explaiin how as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of your scripts that is attached to a gameobject inside Update method call this block,

```
void Update()
{
    // call this block
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        Application.Quit();
        // or ask to quit
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be done within Unity? Or should I be looking for this update in Eclipse after exporting?

Comment: You should do this inside Unity.